# Search component showing last result when input field is cleared using backspace

Tags: reactjs, search, next.js, meilisearch

So I'm using Next.js and built a basic search page with input and storing the results after the query on a state array. The problem is when I clear the input field fast using backspace, it shows the result from the last keyword.

I believe I'm using the React state in the wrong manner.

Here is how I'm querying the search using meilisearch:

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState([]);
const [showSearch, setShowSearch] = useState(false);

async function onChange(e) {
    if (e.length > 0) {

      await client.index('sections')
        .search(e)
        .then((res) => {
          const list = res.hits.map((elm) => ({
            title: elm.Title,
            content: elm.formattedContent
          }));

          setSearch(list);
          setShowSearch(true);
        });
    } else {
      setSearch([]);
      setShowSearch(false);
    }
  }
```

and here is the input field and the search results:

```
<div className="searchPage wrapper">
        <input
          type="text"
          aria-label="Search through site content"
          placeholder="Search your keywords"
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value);}
        />

        {showSearch && (
          <div className="searchPageResults">
            <p className="suggested">Top Results</p>
            {search.length > 0 ? (
              <ul>
                {search.map((item, index) => (
                  <li key={`search-${index}`}>
                    <Link href={`/${item.slug}`}>
                      <a role="link">
                        {item.title}
                      </a>
                    </Link>

                    <p>{item.content}</p>
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            ) : (
              <p className="noResults">No results found</p>
            )}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
```

What are the best practices to prevent this kind of situation?

You can check the live implementation here: https://budgetbasics.openbudgetsindia.org/search

To reproduce the issue:

- Search something, eg: `Budget`
- After the results are shown, hold backspace, when the field is cleared, search results are shown for `b`
- Issue is not there if I select all the text in the field and delete it using backspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

I suspect that when you quickly backspace that the last request made with "b" resolves asynchronously ***after*** the last `onChange` call is made where `e.length > 0` is false. The `search` state is updated to an empty array and once the final asynchronous request resolves the `search` state is updated with the result of "b".

## Solution

One possible solution would be to debounce the `onChange` handler so useless requests aren't made for fast typers. [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) from lodash is a common utility. I used a delay of `300ms`, but this is obviously tunable to suit your needs and what feels best for you or your general users.

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

async function onChange(e) {
  if (e.length > 0) {
    await client.index('sections')
      .search(e)
      .then((res) => {
        const list = res.hits.map((elm) => ({
          title: elm.Title,
          content: elm.formattedContent
        }));

        setSearch(list);
        setShowSearch(true);
      });
  } else {
    setSearch([]);
    setShowSearch(false);
  }
}

const debouncedOnChange = useMemo(() => debounce(onChange, 300), []);

...

<input
  type="text"
  aria-label="Search through site content"
  placeholder="Search your keywords"
  onChange={(e) => debouncedOnChange(e.target.value)} // <-- use debounced handler
/>
```

Comment: btw useMemo is only for optimization right?

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed Yes. Since this is a function component you don't generally want to redeclare the debounced callback each render. I did try this out in a codesandbox without the `useMemo` hook and it still appeared to work, but I suspect that was only because the input is an uncontrolled input.

Comment: in this case, the handler is a function, therefore we'd better `useCallback` instead of `useMemo`, the latter being mostly used to memoize __values__ that are computationally expensive. `useCallback` will memoize the function itself.

Comment: @Madrus I wouldn't necessarily agree that it's ***objectively better*** to use the `useCallback` hook here. `useCallback` and `useMemo` are *nearly* identical. See [useCallback](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) and note that "`useCallback(fn, deps)` is equivalent to `useMemo(() => fn, deps)`". They are both used to memoize *a value*, `useCallback` is a "special case" where the value is specifically *a function*.

Comment: @Madrus To your point though, `useCallback(debounce(onChange, 300), []);` *should* work about the same, but I think `debounce(onChange, 300)` will be called each time the component is rendered, which incurs a slight cost. Using the `useMemo` hook it's only ever called when the hook's callback is invoked, i.e. when a dependency changes.